# Python basic tree visualization

Tags: python, graph, tree, visualization, graph-visualization

I'm trying to draw basic tree in Python.

I've tried to use: igraph, plotly, pygraphviz, and nothing works.

Tried to use igraph. 
By this link: [Error with igraph library - deprecated library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200707/error-with-igraph-library-deprecated-library)
I understood that my version my not be ok (it was 0.1.11)

So now i've trying `pip install python-igraph but receiving:

```
Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.
WARNING: we were not able to detect where igraph is installed on
your machine (if it is installed at all). We will use the fallback
library and include pathss hardcoded in setup.py and hope that the
C core of igraph is installed there.
```

Also tried with Plotly from this link:
https://plot.ly/python/tree-plots/

I've seen it was also recomended by people in stackoverflow.
But the problem is that `es = EdgeSeq(G) # sequence of edges`
EdgeSeq is not defined and I don't know where it came from, so it won't run.

Also tried pygraphviz from this post:
[Drawing & Rendering Multiway Tree in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020741/drawing-rendering-multiway-tree-in-python)

But - cann't install pygraphviz:

```
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I've downloaded and installed all of the necessary files:
vs_community__1763767426.1540655788, vs_buildtools__1763767426.1540655788, 
but the error still comes back.

Also tried using 'ete2', http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html

but couldn't install:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\PC-1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d0hxeuwj\ete2\setup.py", line 90
        print "Installing ETE (A python Environment for Tree Exploration)."
                                                                          ^
```

I've looked deeply into each of my ways and tried to solve the error, without success.
Please help me fix one of the ways, or to find an alternative way to draw trees in python.

Thanks

Comment: try this `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Tried, it didn't fix

Comment: which python version and os are you using and do you use anaconda/conda?

Comment: Windows 10, Virtual Env with python 3.6, no conda nor anaconda

Comment: Found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586520/can-one-get-hierarchical-graphs-from-networkx-with-python-3/29597209